# How to put a text inside a circle?

Tags: html, css

The page is in HTML and I've been trying with CSS with but can't get it right.
This is where i 've been :

```
.box3 {
background-color:yellow;
width:200px;
height:200px;
margin:20px auto;
border-radius:100% }
```

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What did you try, and how is it different from what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: This may help you: https://css-tricks.com/using-css-to-set-text-inside-a-circle/

Answer (score -1):

follow this

```css
.box3 {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  border-radius:100% ;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  background-color:yellow;
  margin:20px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box3">Hello I am A Circle</div>
```

Comment: Thanks mate for helping.But if you write a bigger text , it breaks it kai puts it outside and under the circle !

Comment: @GeorgeSevastiadis I have provided a link in my comment to your question. That should help you.

Comment: you didn't mention to responsive, for responsive circle check this https://codepen.io/cbracco/pen/qnduh